# Mapping Json String with Nested Classes

Tags: java, gson

I have the following JSON String extracted fro MongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "552645a5d3d57a6fc594c3c6"} , "name" : "mark" , 
"Info" : { "age" : 18 , "email" : "mark@gmail.com" , "phone" : "321-456-778"}}
```

I'm trying to map the above JSON to the following class:

```
public class User {

    String name;
    Info info;

    // Getters/Setters
    public User(String name, int age, String email, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.info = new Info(age, email, phone);
    }


    static class Info{

        public Info(int age, String email, String phone) {
            super();
            this.email = email;
            this.phone = phone;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public Info( ) {
        }

        String email;
        String phone;
        int age;
        // Getters/Setters

    }
}
```

By using the `fromJson` method of `Gson`:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User u = gson.fromJson(jsonString, User.class);
```

The resulting `User` has a null `Info` attached to it. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: please check your class implementation, here class name is User and constructor is for Customer and next class name is User and constructor is for Info

Comment: beg your pardon. Did some mess with the editor. Now I have corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in Json. Actually this Json is following mix naming strategy.

the "info" object is coming in camel case and others are coming in small case.
thats why it is difficult for gson to convert it into Object.

If you can convert all keys into lower then your code will work fine.
If you want all your keys to be in camel case then you can use GsonBuilder to configure naming policy.

E.g :

```
GsonBuilder builder=new GsonBuilder();

builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);

Gson g=builder.create();
```

but for your case a simple work-around would be to convert info object into lower case i.e. your converted json will be :

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "552645a5d3d57a6fc594c3c6"} , "name" : "mark" , 
"info" : { "age" : 18 , "email" : "mark@gmail.com" , "phone" : "321-456-778"}}
```